# Google Calendar data reader in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I need to display the next 5 events stating today where the data source for those events is a Google Calendar feed. You may think this is a simple task by simply using an ajax call to get the appropriate feed and iterate through events.

But a feed can contain a re-occuring event with a bunch of attributes describe how it re-occurs (eg: a weekly basis or monthly basis, start and end time, a set of dates that do not apply, etc). So getting a list of events is not as simple as iterating and mapping a collection objects.

Is there a JavaScript reader, preferably in the form of a jQuery plugin, that allow me to easily query the next 5 events starting today?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `singleEvents:true` parameter of the `events.list` API to return each individual occurrence of a recurring event. You don't need a "JavaScript reader", whatever that means, or a jQuery plugin; just use the v3 Calendar API. The other parameters you might be interested in are `maxResults:5` and `timeMin:yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00Z`.

You will need an API key to use the API but if the feed you are referring to is public there should be no authorization issues.

Google for "google calendar api v3 javascript" and you will find several relevant resources.